# Javascript, problem calling function, key event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm practicing js and for long time i cant solve problem bellow.

I have function for changing the blurry background "changeBg", but it does not work when called.

Also key event function are not working dont know why.

I will appreciate any hints where to search for problems.

I know the code is wet but it's far from end "product".

```js
 //counting img tags
  var n = $("img").length;
  var m = n - 2;
  //alert("jest " + m + "tagow img");
  //adding onclick to source of file
  var source = $(".slider-inner > img").attr("src");
  $(".slider-inner > img").attr("onclick", "location.href=\'" + source + "\'");
  for (i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
    $(".dotcontainer").append($("<div class=\"dot\">x</div>"));
    $('.slider-inner img').attr('id', function (i) {
      return 'x' + (i + 1);
    });
    $('.dotcontainer div').attr('id', function (i) {
      return 'x' + (i + 1);
    });
    var url = $('.slider-inner img:nth-child(' + i + ')').attr("src");
     console.log(i);
  }
    ///temporary solution for initial background
      $(".bg").css('background', "url('"+ source +"')");
      $(".bg").css('background-repeat', "no-repeat");
      $(".bg").css('background-size', "cover");
      $(".bg").css('background-position', "center");
      //making first dot active
      $('.dotcontainer div:nth-child(' + 1 + ')').addClass('activee');
      //function changing backgorund
      
function changeBg() {
$(".bg").css('background', "url('"+ source +"')");
$(".bg").css('background-repeat', "no-repeat");
$(".bg").css('background-size', "cover");
$(".bg").css('background-position', "center");
};

    // next buttton

  $('.next').on('click', function nextImage() {
    var currentImg = $('.active');
    var nextImg = currentImg.next();
    var currentdot = $('.activee');
    var nextdot = currentdot.next();
    if (nextImg.length) {
      currentImg.removeClass('active').css('z-index', -10);
      nextImg.addClass('active').css('z-index', 10);
      currentdot.removeClass('activee');
      nextdot.addClass('activee');
      var source = nextImg.attr("src");
      nextImg.attr("onclick", "location.href=\'" + source + "\'");
      changeBg();
      } else {
      currentImg.removeClass('active').css('z-index', -10);
      $('#x1').addClass('active').css('z-index', 10);
      currentdot.removeClass('activee');
      $('.dotcontainer div:nth-child(' + 1 + ')').addClass('activee');
    }
  });



//prev button
  $('.prev').on('click', function prevImage() {
    var currentImg = $('.active');
    var prevImg = currentImg.prev();
    var currentdot = $('.activee');
    var prevdot = currentdot.prev();
    var n = $("img").length;
    var m = n - 2;
    if (prevImg.length) {
      currentImg.removeClass('active').css('z-index', -10);
      prevImg.addClass('active').css('z-index', 10);
      currentdot.removeClass('activee');
      prevdot.addClass('activee');
      changeBg();
    } else {
      currentImg.removeClass('active').css('z-index', -10);
      $('.slider-inner img:nth-child(' + m + ')').addClass('active').css('z-index', 10);
      currentdot.removeClass('activee');
      $('.dotcontainer div:nth-child(' + m + ')').addClass('activee');
    }
  });

//switch active dots
   $(".dot").click(function (event) {
    $('.activee').attr('class', 'dot');
    $(this).attr('class', 'dot activee'); 
    var aktkrop = $(".activee").attr("id");
    var fotoa = $('.slider-inner .active').attr("id");
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    $("#" + aktkrop).attr("class", "active")
  });


//temp shadowbox temporary solution
    $('.btn').on('click', function () {
    $(".boxx").css("display", "block");
  });
  $('.close').on('click', function () {
    $(".boxx").css("display", "none");
  });



   document.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){
      if (e.keyCode === 37) {
      prevImage();
    } else if(e.keyCode === 39) {
      nextImage();
    }
  });
```

```css
body {
 font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #fff;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-position: center;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;

}
.bg{
 z-index: -2;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 filter: blur(30px);
 -webkit-filter: blur(30px);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-position: center;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.blackshadow{
 z-index: -1;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: black;
 opacity: 0.6;
}


a {
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
}

h1 {
 text-align: center;
}

.container {
 width: 540px;
 margin: 40px auto;
 overflow: auto;

}

.slider-inner {
 width: 500px;
 height: 300px;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 float: left;
 padding: 3px;
 border: #666 solid 1px;
}

.slider-inner img {
 display: none;
 width: 500px;
 height: 300px;
}

.slider-inner img.active {
 display: inline-block;
}

.prev,
.next {
 float: left;
 margin-top: 130px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.prev {
 position: relative;
 margin-right: -45px;
 z-index: 100;
}

.next {
 position: relative;
 margin-left: -45px;
 z-index: 100;
}

.buba {

 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
}

.dotcontainer {
 position: relative;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 align-items: center;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
}

.dot {
 cursor: pointer;
 margin: 5px;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 background-color: gray;
 border-radius: 50%;
 text-align: center;
 justify-content: center;
 color: black;
 font-weight: 800;
}

.activee {
 background-color: white;
}

.boxx {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: black;
 opacity: 0.6;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 11;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 display: none;
}

.close {
 margin-left: 300px;
 margin-top: 300px;
 z-index: 11;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
 <title>Page Title</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="bg"></div>
 <div class="blackshadow"></div>
 
  <div class="boxx">
   <div class="closee">
    <button class="close">Close</button>
   </div>
  </div>
  <button class="btn">Kliknij</button>
  <div class="container">
   <h1>JQSlider</h1>
   
   <div class="slider-outer">
    <img src="http://www.fotem.pl/data/7d87e07a3066629171add66003d.png" id="prev" class="prev" alt="Prev">
    <div class="slider-inner">



     <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/01/14/23/12/nature-3082832_1280.jpg" class="active">
     <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/01/20/28/green-1072828_1280.jpg">
     <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_1280.jpg">
     <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/06/19/21/24/the-road-815297_1280.jpg">
     <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/01/28/23/35/landscape-615429_1280.jpg">
     <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/09/30/14/51/squirrel-4515962_1280.jpg">
     <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/07/22/16/29/fog-1535201_1280.jpg">
     <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/23/13/48/beach-1852945_1280.jpg">



    </div>


    <img src="http://www.fotem.pl/data/6f1498615d84ca14dbf0de784bd.png" id="next" class="next" alt="Next">
   </div>
  </div>



  <div class="dotcontainer">
  </div>
 
 </body>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js">

 </script>

</html>
```

Thank you in advance.

Code:
https://codepen.io/odzeradodeveloperajava/pen/EMLbzz

Comment: Java has nothing to do with JavaScript. Please tag your questions appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The background did not change as the source variable was not up-to date with the image src. You will need to ensure, that the source is not only declared once, but the value in it will always be updated on every event.

The keyup event handler is throwing exceptions as it cannot access the nextImage() and prevImage() methods. You will need to separate the methods and re-use them when needed as callBackFunction or just call it directly:

```
function prevImage() {
    // code inside
}

function nextImage() {
    // code inside
}

$('.next').on('click', nextImage);
$('.prev').on('click', prevImage);

document.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 37) {
        prevImage();
    } else if (e.keyCode === 39) {
        nextImage();
    }
});
```

I've made several changes to the example you've shared. Here is a working Pen: https://codepen.io/attila-antal/pen/KKKVGEd

Comment: Thank You! Also great solution.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you have to declare your function nextImage and prevImage outside of the event listener. for example:

```
function nextImage() {
// your code
}

$('.next').on('click', nextImage);
```

The background does not change because you have to pass new source to your function. for example:

```
function changeBg(source) {
// your code
}
```

When you want to invoke changeBg function you should pass new source: for example: `changeBg(newImageUrl);`

Comment: Thank You! I uderstand it now.